# Convert image to HEIC/HEIF in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin Form Project where we need to Take a photo or upload a photo in the app and compress the photo and convert it to HEIC/HEIF before uploading to the server. We used Plugin.Media.CrossMedia before but that library is converting image to Jpg after taking photo/upload from gallery. And we also use cross media to compress the image. Is there a way in Xamarin to convert image to HEIC/HEIF and compress the image?

Comment: You probably need to use the IOS camera API to save the original image in that format

Comment: After iOS 11, the default format for taking photos is HEIC format, and you can save them directly.

Answer (score 0):

For in-program photo upload, you can use Renderer to customize ContentPage, refer to [the sample of the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-contentpage/) (it should be noted that AVCaptureStillImageOutput class is deprecated), you can use Apple's [AVCapturePhotoOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput?language=objc) class to capture a photo, use the [AVCapturePhotoSettings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings?language=objc) class to change the data format of the photo to HEIF/HEVC format, and then [save the image for upload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/photo_capture/capturing_still_and_live_photos?language=objc). (Video captured on the iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus, and iPhone X running iOS 11 or later uses the HEVC codec by default). For more details, please refer to Apple's official documentation:[Capturing Still and Live Photos|Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/photo_capture/capturing_still_and_live_photos?language=objc)